# Using an exception vs returning string as message

Tags: c#, exception

If I am writing an API that takes an int parsed from a string, is it a good idea to seperate the parse method from the method that would do something with the "out" value?

My reason for thinking yes is that the code will be more clear. E.g. if I get an exception related to the parse, I can say in the stack "ah yes, that would be the top method called Parse() obviously!" before even looking at the codebase. I believe null is the wrong choice as it could introduce bugs by other developers who do not understand the technical decisions made (though I document this religously).

However, in a method that is 5 levels deep in the stack, how could I "Relay" an error string message?

Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't your API just take an int and let the client code parse it before passing?

Comment: Throw an exception and let it bubble up.  Give it a reasonable error string and you should be fine.

Comment: How complicated is the parsing? If you're just using Int.Parse and an exception is thrown, Int.Parse will be at the top of the call stack -- no matter if it's in this method or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to relay the error string message, create an exception and use the "throw" keyword.

As for separating the parse method, is this what you are asking for?

```
int myInt;
if(!Int32.TryParse(inputString, out int myInt))
    throw new System.ArgumentException("Invalid Argument", "inputString");

methodThatUsesInt(myInt);
```

Comment: What I meant was 2 seperate methods eg... ParseNumber(); and then your methodThatUsesInt(myInt); I find that sort of layout easy to understand for people who support systems (I am in 3rd line support). Is there a way to throw just the string up? (I believe not).

Comment: I updated the response to show the implemented exception.  The first argument in the ArgumentException is the exception message, the second is the parameter that you checked.

Comment: I also reformatted the solution to reflect the "two separate methods"

Answer (score 0):

You should have it throw an [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear.  Are you saying that your method takes a string, which is supposed to be parse-able as an integer, and then does something with the numeric result of such parsing?

If it is unlikely that your method will be fed a lot of invalid strings, and if there is nothing useful your routine can do if it receives an invalid string, it would probably be best for your method to throw an exception when an invalid string is passed in.  If your method does sufficiently-complex parsing that the caller could not very well validate a string without doing as much work as your routine will do parsing it, and your routine will be expected to deal with all the good strings in a batch containing a mixture of good and bad strings, a common pattern would be to expose a method in the style of `bool TryParse(string st, ref int result)`.  Personally, I don't like that pattern, since it provides no mechanism for indicating the reason for a parsing failure.  I would recommend a different pattern--something like one of these:

```
int TryParse(string st, out ParseStatus status);
int TryParse(string st, Action<ParseStatus> failureAction);
delegate void ActionRV<RefT,ValT>(ref RefT refparam, ValT valparam);
int TryParse<RefPT>(string st, ActionRV<RefT, ParseStatus> FailureAction, 
                        ref RefT refParam);
```

In all three of these calling patterns, if `ParseStatus` is an inheritable type, it will be possible for `TryParse` to supply an instance of `ParseStatus` or a derived type which precisely describes the failure.  In the case of the second and third pattern, the delegate could throw an exception itself, store in `ParseStatus` a value which should be returned to the calling function, or perhaps do something like munge the original parameter string (if it's stored in `ParseStatus`) and set a flag to request a "retry".  I personally like the third form, since I think `ref` parameters should be preferred over closures in cases where either could work.  Note that the second form can be efficiently implemented in terms of the third form:

```
static ExecAction<T>(T param, ref Action<T> proc)
{
  proc(param);
}
int TryParse(string st, Action<ParseStatus> failureAction)
{
  TryParse(st, ExecAction, ref failureAction);
}
```

Note that passing the `failureAction` as the ref parameter means it's possible to use a static delegate for the wrapper function instead of having to use a closure.